# Why did Mhenni Benghorbal get suspended?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

Just checked his profile page:

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/35472/mhenni-benghorbal

and it says "This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends in 5 days."

Why is that?

Comment: Only one person can answer this question: Mhenni Benghorbal. The moderators are not at liberty to disclose specific information regarding suspensions. (And I believe the Stack Exchange employees are also so limited.)

Comment: But your question could also be understood as a more general question: *What are possible reasons why a user can be suspended?* in such case, see [Suspension Reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23366/suspension-reasons).

Comment: Hopefully he will see this question and tell us why he was wrongly suspended then.

Comment: I am curious how you, without any knowledge of the situation (you basically admitted as much in the question), could have decided that the user was "wrongly suspended".

Comment: @WillieWong Because he is a professor...

Comment: Last I checked, "not violating rules on math.SE" is not a prerequisite for appointment to _any_ job. I fail to see the relevance of what he does for a living to this discussion.

Comment: @WillieWong: I imagine that someone who has violated the rules on (math.)SE would have a difficult time becoming a Community Manager with SE.  But I guess that's slightly beside the point. ;-)

Comment: Sometimes professors, even math professors, [behave badly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Kaczynski).

Comment: @ArthurFischer One of my favorite things is the first footnote in [this paper](http://faculty.valpo.edu/lpudwell/papers/mm005281.pdf).

Comment: Dear @Willie: as far as I can see the  OP did not claim that the user was "wrongly" suspended . The question seems in good faith to me and may very well arise out of genuine curiosity (anyway I give the OP the benefit of the doubt).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg See the third comment. It was in jest though.

Comment: Dear @Oliver: thanks for the clarification. And apologies to Willie for my confusion of your comment with the OP's question.

Comment: @T.Bongers Bwahaha, very good footnote :)

Comment: BTW @Oliver: I see no evidence that he is in fact currently a professor. As a professor, I make no claims to be beyond reproach, and certainly MhenniB and I have squabbled numerous times, particularly when he made hasty and wrong or unhelpful posts.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, only the person who was suspended can answer this question at this point due to privacy issues.

That said: It is unreasonable to assume that professors are "immune" to the faults that warrant suspension.  While some forums may only suspend active "spammers," Math.SE moderators (or the system itself, I believe) can suspend users for many reasons aside from blatant off-topic posts.